# Using the any schema element in wsdl with PHP SoapServer

Tags: php, xsd, wsdl, soapserver

I can't seem to get the XSD  element to work in my wsdl using PHP SoapServer. According to everything I have read and seeing how a couple of other companies implement "loose typed" wsdls. The following should be sufficient for retrieving and sending records information.

```
<complexType name="Record">
    <sequence>
        <any namespace="##targetNamespace" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the php SoapServer class throws away any elements that are not strictly defined. What I get is empty records on create requests and send empty records on retrieve/filter requests, though the fields are clearly there before the SoapServer handling.

If I specifically define the fields that are missing like this...

```
<complexType name="Record">
    <sequence>
        <element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="LastName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <any namespace="##targetNamespace" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

then all is well and those fields get passed to/from the client. Am I missing something? I have tried all of the namespace options ##any, ##local, etc. and the processContents options. I just want to be able to send/return extra fields of a record regardless if they are detailed out in the schema or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SoapVar object in your return object that you pass to the soap response. 
In your case the object returned should look something like this.

```
$recordObject = new stdClass;
$recordObject->prop1 = 'prop1';
$recordObject->prop2 = 'prop2';

$soapReturnObject = new SoapVar($recordObject, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
```

See also : [SOAP: Returning an array of xsd:any elements in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836242/soap-returning-an-array-of-xsdany-elements-in-php/23013813#23013813)