# PHP get data from web services that returns an stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, object, stdclass

I am trying to get the values from my web service using the following code:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url);     
$response = $client->GetInfoByNumeroContrato(array(
   'schema' => $schema, 
   'numContrato' => $numContract
));
```

I have a method called `GetInfoByNumeroContrato` that receives two parameters.
When I call my web service the `$response` gives me a `stdClass` Object as shown below:

```
stdClass Object
(
[GetInfoByNumeroContratoResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [schema] => 
        [any] => 000559500trueTITULAR BNMARIA  DORES  PEIXOTO220125424DORESRIBEIRO50@GMAIL.COMR DAMIAO DE GOIS ENTRADA 71 BL 1 1 ANDAR N 90000003194460-2921646013411950-10-07T00:00:00+01:00Divorciado003501600006968540097PT50003501600006968540097CGDIPTPLBilhete de IdentidadeSENHORA DA HORAFeminino4010003002015-09-16T00:00:00+01:0024.90falseSENIORtrue2015-10-05T00:00:00+01:00true2016-09-05T00:00:00+01:002015-11-05T00:00:00+00:00M0PT47111799DÉBITO DIRETOCONNECTA000559500falseAGREGADOJOSE  LUIS RIBEIRO  FAIEL220125424R DAMIAO DE GOIS ENTRADA 71 BL 1 1 ANDAR N 90000003204460-2921646013411983-08-23T00:00:00+01:00Outro003501600006968540097Bilhete de IdentidadeSENHORA DA HORAMasculino4010003012015-09-16T00:00:00+01:0024.90falseSENIORtrue2015-10-05T00:00:00+01:00true2016-09-05T00:00:00+01:002015-11-05T00:00:00+00:00M0PT47111799DÉBITO DIRETOCONNECTA
    )

[_exception] => 
)
```

The idea is to get each value individually from [any] and the POST each one.  For example get "000559500" then "true" and so on.

I have already tried to parse this but without success.
Is there any better way to go about this?

When I do the following:

```
print $response->GetInfoByNumeroContratoResult->any;
```

I get the following answer:

```
000559500trueTITULAR BNMARIA DORES PEIXOTO220125424DORESRIBEIRO50@GMAIL.COMR   DAMIAO DE GOIS ENTRADA 71 BL 1 1 ANDAR N 90000003194460-2921646013411950-10-07T00:00:00+01:00Divorciado003501600006968540097PT50003501600006968540097CGDIPTPLBilhete de IdentidadeSENHORA DA HORAFeminino4010003002015-09-16T00:00:00+01:0024.90falseSENIORtrue2015-10-05T00:00:00+01:00true2016-09-05T00:00:00+01:002015-11-05T00:00:00+00:00M0PT47111799DÉBITO DIRETOCONNECTA000559500falseAGREGADOJOSE LUIS RIBEIRO FAIEL220125424R DAMIAO DE GOIS ENTRADA 71 BL 1 1 ANDAR N 90000003204460-2921646013411983-08-23T00:00:00+01:00Outro003501600006968540097Bilhete de IdentidadeSENHORA DA HORAMasculino4010003012015-09-16T00:00:00+01:0024.90falseSENIORtrue2015-10-05T00:00:00+01:00true2016-09-05T00:00:00+01:002015-11-05T00:00:00+00:00M0PT47111799DÉBITO DIRETOCONNECTA
```

Is it possible to get one by one?

Is it possible to receive from the web service insted getting every thing in [any] recive for example: [contractNumer] => value then [Name] => value and so on? Individualy?

Comment: Post your client's code, it is too difficult to know what is wrong from what you've provided so far.

Comment: what does `print $response->GetInfoByNumeroContratoResult->any;` output?

Comment: also update your question with the code for the `GetInfoByNumeroContrato` method

Comment: When I post print $response->GetInfoByNumeroContratoResult->any I get the following:  000559500trueTITULAR BNMARIA DORES PEIXOTO220125424DORESRIBEIRO50@GMAIL.COMR DAMIAO DE GOIS ENTRADA 71 BL 1 1 ANDAR N 90000003194460...

Comment: I get all the values at at once.

Comment: If you're using the `SoapClient` class you sould be able to dump the entire response using something like `$response = $client->__getLastResponse();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836242/soap-returning-an-array-of-xsdany-elements-in-php

Comment: using this: $response = $client->__getLastResponse(); got a blank answer.

Comment: What is `$schema` and `$numContract`, how are they declared and have you tried making the request without one or both of these parameters?

Comment: $numContract is number contract for a person.  $schema is if that person has purchased a type of contract. $schema is type of contract The request has to be with both these parameters.

Comment: Can you show how you declare the two parameters in your code?

Comment: The two paramateres are sent from an url. I then do $_GET of those parameters send those parameters to a function where in that function I create a soap cliente and call the metodo GetInfoByNumeroContratoResult and sending those parameters to the web service.

Comment: Is it possible to receive from the web service insted getting every thing in [any] recive for example: [contractNumer] => value then [Name] => value and so on? Individualy?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but might save hours for someone else:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_string($response->GetInfoByNumeroContratoResult->any);

print_r($xml);  //an array containing the whole XML

print $x->contractNumber; //individually
```